# HTML + CSS (maybe Bootstrap Framework) creating LI 1 2 3 list

Tags: html, css, list

Good day,

I have a pretty vague question. I would like to make the following in HTML :
[image]

Though I have no clue what's it called.
I want to use it like following:

1. Go to our website
2. Click on create account button in the left top corner
3. Fill in your data
4. Click finish and HAVE FUN

Something like that.

But I would like to do this in HTML & CSS and I do not exactly know how to describe just that.

*edit, I see a minus. But I simply do not know how to name this in proper English so finding an answer online is very difficult for me. I find a lot of answers but all are off track to what I am looking for.*

Some code was desired so here I am writing it.

I would like to turn the following code into the picture styled above

```
<ol>
    <li>Go to our website</li>
    <li>Click on create account button in the left top corner</li>
    <li>Fill in your data</li>
    <li>Click finish and HAVE FUN</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Hi,Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, We cannot help you if you do not provide any code, can you please put your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood correctly, you want something like this. I know there's a proper way to make it. But, hopefully someone will be able to provide you with a better example.

I wanted to leave this as a comment in the form of a [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/RaysOfTheSun/yLxcjzo7/5/) instead. But, I don't have that privilege yet.

```css
.vl {
    border-left: 2px solid #FF4500;
    height: 300px;
  transform: translatex(90px);
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-2;
}

.bullet-less {
 list-style:none;
}

.round-item {
 border: thin solid #FFA500;
 border-radius: 30px;
 padding: 20px;
 text-align:center;
 margin: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 font-weight:bold;
 background-color: #FFA500;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="vl"></div>
 <ul class="bullet-less">
  <li class="round-item">1</li>
  <li class="round-item">2</li>
  <li class="round-item">3</li>
  <li class="round-item">4</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly!! Outstanding!! Now probably even more important to me. What is this called?? My question was rated as not useful several times and noted that I had to write some code. But I had zero clue what it was even called. Let aside tell people where to start!!

Thanks!!

Comment: Well the list of numbers you wanted reminds me of a binary tree :)